# Why my IF statement doesn't work

Tags: vb.net, if-statement

The task is to produce a rating system, so when users type in their rating out of 5, which will then be shown in stars below:


e.g. `4 = ****`
But I believe I am writing my code correctly but it still doesn't seem to execute correctly.

```
 Protected Sub btnRate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnRate.Click

        Dim txtStar As Integer

        If txtStar = "1" Then
            lblStar.Text = "*"
        End If

        If txtStar = "2" Then
            lblStar.Text = "**"
        End If

        If txtStar = "3" Then
            lblStar.Text = "***"
        End If

        If txtStar = "4" Then
            lblStar.Text = "****"
        End If

        If txtStar = "5" Then
            lblStar.Text = "*****"
        End If

    End Sub
End Class
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: This looks like a homework assignment, so I won't take you the whole way, but you'd want to look at `If txtStar.Text = "1" Then` kind of thing... Good luck and hope this moves you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks, I understand it, but the main problem is that the answer doesnt appear in the label

Comment: Put Option Strict On at the top of your code or set it in the project properties.  That should be your first step.  You have declared txtStar as an Integer, but you are comparing it like a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this one.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim rate As Integer
    rate  = txtStar.Text
    lblStar.Text = String.Empty
    For index = 1 To rate
        lblStar.Text += "*"
    Next
End Sub
```

**Edit**

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim rate As Integer
    rate = txtStar.Text
    If rate = 1 Then
        lblStar.Text = "*"
    ElseIf rate = 2 Then
        lblStar.Text = "**"
    ElseIf rate = 3 Then
        lblStar.Text = "***"
    ElseIf rate = 4 Then
        lblStar.Text = "****"
    ElseIf rate = 5 Then
        lblStar.Text = "*****"
    Else
        lblStar.Text = String.Empty
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks, but i need to use If Statements

Comment: Better to use the string constructor `String(char c, int count)`

Comment: I would but i havent learned that yet, thanks though. but the main problem is that the answer doesnt appear in the label

Comment: @Magnus yup but `user1944225` want a simple codes :)

Comment: i updated my answer. hope it will helps.

Comment: @user1944225 You say: "I haven't learned that yet". Well you have learnt it now.

Comment: @Magnus haha,the teacher needs to teach me it before i can use it, but do you now why it doesnt appear in the label, when you press the button?

Comment: @spajce Thankyou  very much, i didnt read your answer properly, but it really helped

Answer (score 0):

So `txtStar` is the TextBox. The you should use `Int32.Parse` or `TryParse` to convert the text to a number, then you can use [this string constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xsa4321w.aspx):

```
Dim starCount As Int32
Dim canBeParsed = Int32.TryParse(txtStar.Text, starCount)
If canBeParsed Then
    lblStar.Text = New String("*"c, starCount)
End If
```

Comment: How would that differ from the result of the original code?

Comment: thanks for the answer, but for some reason, when I press the button the stars dont come up in the label

Comment: @user1944225: I've edited my answer meanwhile, have a look.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I havent been taught "parssing" yet, so I cant use it

Answer (score 0):

If txtStar is a textBox then you should compare the Text property of this textbox against your constants

```
   If txtStar.Text = "1" Then
       lblStar.Text = "*"
   End If
```

and so on ...

however is it not clear what is the meaning of the integer variable declared in your code

```
 Dim txtStar As Integer
```

you don't set an initial value so I suppose that this is just a dead code and thus can be removed.
But in case you want to use it you need to assign a value and then compare....

```
txtStar = Convert.ToInt32(txtStar.Text)
If txtStar = 1 Then
    lblStar.Text = "*"
End If
```

Notice how I have removed the comparison with a string constant and used an integer constant.
Also a different name for this variable could be less confusing.....

Comment: When I changed it to txtStar.text, it came up with an error of 'Text' is not a member of 'String'

Comment: If I take away that part of the code, it comes up with many errors, ive been taught to always declare the variable

Comment: OK, I see you have found your answer, however i really suggest you to investigate the [Option Strict On  and Option Explicit](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311329) instructions and why thewy are useful

Comment: Okay, thanks for that, what will these option do??

Comment: Your accepted answer use a string as an integer. This is possible only because VB.NET should maintain a certain degree of compatibility with the old VB6. But is generally considered a bad practice allow this kind of implicit conversions. The `Option Strict On` will forbid the conversion and thus you are forced to write more formally correct programs.